# Load only a part of a ini file in php

Tags: php, class, load, ini

I have this code that loads a file .ini:

```
class Page{

    public $lang;

    function __construct($lang){
        $this->lang = $lang;
        $this->page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");
    }

    public function writeContent($part){
        $load_page = parse_ini_file('lang/'.$this->lang.'.content.ini', true);
        return $load_page[$this->page][$part];
    }

}
```

This loads a file like "it.content.ini" or "en.content.ini"...
The ini file is structured like this:

```
[page-name-one]
title = "THE TITLE"

caption1 = "Text one"
caption2 = "Text two"

[page-name-two]
title = "THE TITLE OF THE SECOND PAGE"

caption1 = "Text one second page"
caption2 = "Text two second page"
```

This works perfectly as it loads the file and shows me the section (between square-brackets) based on the page name.

Is it possible to load only a part of the ini file without using multiple files?

When I load index.php I'd like the PHP to actually load the ini file ONLY for the [index] part  of the ini file so that if the file is actually big I only load a part of it. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, if you write your own ini parser.

Comment: Ok... can you give me some data about it? How? Where do I find a documentation for it? Examples?

Comment: i wouldn't worry about the page size, just use the whole file. its very common to load a lot of theses that may not be used on every page.

Comment: keep the languages in separate files.. that is how i've always seen it done

Comment: Yes user20232359723568423357842364 that's what i do already, but each language (file) has quite a lot of text in it

Comment: @NDLombardi Then you may doing it wrong with inis. If you have so much text I'd eventually consider migrating the whole thing to a database...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`Zend_Config_Ini`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html) part of the Zend Framework. You can easily load part of the config file using that.

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/config.ini', 'section_name');
```

Comment: yes you can just use this class no problem, you don't need to use the entire stack

Answer (score 0):

Please, see the [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function

Comment: link only answers are not encouraged.

Comment: Dagon, oops. Sorry. I did not know that :(

Comment: a link for your reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers